# How do i combine multiple bar charts in bokeh?

Tags: python, bar-chart, bokeh

I want to plot two bar charts on the same figure.

One will have only positive values, one will have only negative values.

I want the positive bars in green (above the x-axis) and the negative bars in red (below the x-axis)

**Questions:**

**1. Is it possible to do this with the existing highlevel Bar method in the bokeh.charts interface?**

**2. If not, how can I create a bar chart using the lower level bokeh.plotting interface? (rather than the higher level bokeh.charts interface)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The answer below is a few years out of date. All sorts of bar plots (stacked, grouped, color mapped) are much simpler and easier now. See this section of the user's guide for many examples:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html

---

**1.**
I tried doing multiple bar charts using the highlevel Bar method however, I could not achieve what I wanted and so I used the plotting interface.

**2.**
Is this what you are looking for?

```
    from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

    plot = figure(width=600, height=600, x_range=(0,50), y_range=(-10,10))

    plot.quad(top=[10],bottom=[0],left=[1],right=[2], color='green', line_color='black', legend='positive')
    plot.quad(top=[12],bottom=[0],left=[2],right=[3], color='green', line_color='black', legend='positive')
    plot.quad(top=[1],bottom=[0],left=[3],right=[4], color='green', line_color='black', legend='positive')
    plot.quad(top=[2],bottom=[0],left=[4],right=[5], color='green', line_color='black', legend='positive')
    plot.quad(top=[3],bottom=[0],left=[5],right=[6], color='green', line_color='black', legend='positive')
    plot.quad(top=[4],bottom=[0],left=[6],right=[7], color='green', line_color='black', legend='positive')

    plot.quad(top=[-5],bottom=[0],left=[1],right=[2], color='red', line_color='black', legend='negative')
    plot.quad(top=[-6],bottom=[0],left=[2],right=[3], color='red', line_color='black', legend='negative')
    plot.quad(top=[-2],bottom=[0],left=[3],right=[4], color='red', line_color='black', legend='negative')
    plot.quad(top=[-8],bottom=[0],left=[4],right=[5], color='red', line_color='black', legend='negative')
    plot.quad(top=[-9],bottom=[0],left=[5],right=[6], color='red', line_color='black', legend='negative')
    plot.quad(top=[-10],bottom=[0],left=[6],right=[7], color='red', line_color='black', legend='negative')

    output_file('test.html')
    show(plot)
```

Comment: That'll  do.. Especially if the 'top', 'left' and 'right' inputs can take a dataframe and so I can do this in with only two quads... thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! thank you for accepting the answer!

Comment: Things are *much* easier than this now, see the user's guide for lot of examples of stacked, grouped, or colormapped bar plots: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `vbar_stack` calls:

```
volume_figure.vbar_stack(["buys"], x='timestamp', width=1.0, color=[colors.turquoise], source=source)
volume_figure.vbar_stack(["sells"], x='timestamp', width=1.0, color=[colors.tomato], source=source)
```

In general, bar charts are described in detail in the docs section [Handling Categorical Data](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html)